# why are dashes converted to underscores in optional args but not positional args with argparse

Tags: python, command-line, arguments, command-line-interface, argparse

i am currently building a `cli` tool and came across some head-scratching functionality using the `argparse` module (at least, head-scratching to me). i did a quick `google` search but could not find any answers -- although it is very likely that my search terminology is incorrect.

the behavior is illustrated in the following screenshot:

[image]

here's the situation:

- a positional argument, defined with dashes in the key
- an optional argument, also defined with dashes in the key

when passing the result of `.parse_args()` into `vars()`, the dashes in positional arguments are preserved (as expected) but this doesn't appear to be the case with optional arguments, i.e., with optional arguments, the dashes are converted into underscores.

what am i missing here? i am hoping a python export can explain why this behavior exists.. thanks in advance.

`m`

**ninja edit:**

upon submitting this post it has occurred to me that this might be related to the `--` prefixed used for declaring optional arguments. but i would still like to know the actual reasoning.

**edit:**

it was pointed out to me that this has nothing to do with `vars()` but the question still stands: why is this the behavior?

Comment: I always recommend adding a diagnostic print of `args` before further use.  That will show you exactly what the attribute names are in the result.

Comment: @hpaulj what do you mean by diagnostic print? i've printed the results (as you can see in the screenshot) but that doesn't explain **why** .. or is there something else i should be printing? thanks

Comment: ok i see what you're saying.. you're saying this has nothing to do with `vars()`

Comment: `print(args)`.  You are showing results from `get`

Comment: i get it now, thanks. it still isn't clear to me why it works this way, but ok i can live with this.

Comment: With the screen shot (as opposed to a copy-n-paste) it's easy to miss details, especially when read on small screen.  In any case `argparse` mangles optional's `dest` so you can use `--foo-bar` as flag, but still access the attribute as `args.foo_bar`.  `_` is allowed in variable names, but `-` is not.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#dest explains how `dest` is generated for the 2 kinds of Actions.

Comment: It lets you choose any `dest` for a `positional` because that only appears in your code  If it isn't a valid variable name, that's your problem.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you it is making sense now